# Ruby framework for mobile

Tags: ruby, native

I want to build native mobile application using ruby. I have tried Rhodes and found it to have a commercial licence, which is [not free](http://www.rhomobile.com/rhodes/simplified-licensing/).

Is there another, free Ruby framework for native mobile applications?

Comment: Rhodes is under MIT License. Only the enterprise edition is not free.

Comment: i build native mobile application for my company

Comment: You can use the last free update of Rhodes and RhoSync indefinitely for no further purchase.

Comment: [this](http://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/rhomobile-announces-simplified-pricing-for-rhodes-and-rhosync-62245677.html) say that it free if my source code is open souce under GPLv3.
I do not want my source code open to other people.

Answer (score 1):

Matz has publicized the official mobile ruby called [mruby](https://github.com/mruby/mruby).

Comment: Thanks i see it. But i found it is preliminary release not final release. Can you suggest another ruby framework.

Comment: AFAIK mruby has nothing to do with "mobile", and is simply a lightweight Ruby implementation.

Comment: can i use ruby on rails to develop hybrid mobile application?

Answer (score 1):

There's also [RubyMotion](http://www.rubymotion.com/) for iOS, it isn't free and is certainly expensive...

But it's native.